# How can I use CMake -C option in Android Studio (gradle)?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, cmake

I have to populate the **CMake** variable cache from a file.
I added an argument to     defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.cmake.arguments (`-C options.cmake`).

However, I get this:

> 17:05:13.520 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.api.Project] loading initial
>   cache file  options.cmake 17:05:13.521 [LIFECYCLE]
>   [org.gradle.api.Project] CMake Error: Error processing file: 
>   options.cmake

The file is in the same directory as the build.gradle.
I tried providing the absolute path (with the help of projectDir variable), but it didn't change anything.

**Simple reproduction**

Create an empty Android app in Android Studio.
In MyApplication/app add a simple CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(hello)
```

In the same folder add a simple options.cmake file:

```
set(foo "bar")
```

Note that this is OK for CMake:

```
cd MyApplication/app && mkdir bld && cd bld
cmake -C ../options.cmake ..
```

Now, import the CMakeLists.txt with right-click on the project and 'Link C++ Project with Gradle'

Your build.gradle should now have this:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
```

What I tried doing now was adding the following in **defaultConfig**:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        arguments "-C ${projectDir}/options.cmake"
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. Any other ideas for populating CMake cache?

Comment: What the contents of `options.cmake` look like?

Comment: As simple as possible:
set(foo "bar")

Comment: Try `set(foo "bar" CACHE <type> <docstring>)`.

Comment: That's obviously not the problem here... But I'll try just for completeness.

Comment: No, didn't help :-(

Comment: It seems gradle puts "-C ..." at the end of the command line, and CMake doesn't like it.

Comment: OK, found the solution. Thanks for your help, arrowd!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be quite easy:

Don't put space after "-C"